# Sublime Text not finding gcc compiler

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to run Make from Sublime Text 2, but getting an error:

```
make: arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

This only happens from Sublime Text, when I run from Terminal, everything works fine.

I've setup .bash_profile with

```
export PATH="~/arm-cs-tools/bin:$PATH"
```

...but still no can do? How can i get ST to resolve the $PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [unofficial Sublime Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#troubleshooting-build-systems):

> On some operating systems, the value for PATH will vary from a
>   terminal window to a graphical application. Thus, even if the command
>   you are using in your build system works in the command line, it may
>   not work from Sublime Text. This is due to user profiles in shells.
>
> To solve this issue, make sure you set the desired PATH so that graphical applications such as Sublime Text can find it. See the links below for more information.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the path element in .sublime-build files to override the PATH > used to locate the executable specified in
>   cmd. This new value for PATH will only be in effect for as long as
>   your build system is running. After that, the old PATH will be
>   restored.

Note that while this documentation is for v1 and is deprecated, the official documentation references this passage directly [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html)

So you should be able to define a custom path in the .sublime-build file.  using the `path` option

Comment: I ended up editing the .sublime-build file for the Makefile build system in Sublime Text.